# CanvasAuthorizeAttribute with no extended permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating a canvas application using the Facebook C# SDK and am trying to authenticate the user without asking for any extended permissions.

When the user adds the application the CanvasAuthorize attribute is not redirecting the user to the facebook permissions page.

This process works fine if I ask for "publish_stream" or any other extended permission but I only want to ask for basic permissions initially.

Is there any way to do this using the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version of the SDK (5.0.3) now uses the new oauth page instead of the php plugin to authorize the user. This installs the app even when no extended permissions are specified.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm guessing right the basic permissions you require are FB User Id or may be first, last name, I don't think you'll require to authenticate the user for that. Simply make an object of FacebookApp and try getting the required data, if it does get the basic data then you are good to go, otherwise in the meanwhile I'll try looking into it :)

Cheers,

Nauman

Comment: okay, I've just checked it, you don't require any permissions for getting basic data such as first name, last name, user id etc....

Comment: That's correct but my problem is that the attribute does not redirect the user to the permissions screen (https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?blah), so no bookmark and no entry in the user's privacy settings.